# Magic Number Mismatch error in Android Studio When Generate Sign APK

Tags: android, apk, signing

i have getting a issue when i generate signed APK from android studio 3.1 i get error Magic Number Mismatch.

I already do uninstall android studio and reinstall new copy download and install.

Can you please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Its solved, you need to clear all chache of android studio