# Magic number did not match while generating signed apk

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, signed

I am trying to generate signed apk but I am getting the following error.

I have searched about it but didn't find anything that can resolve this problem.

Solution I've tried

- Invalidate caches/restart
- deleting .gradle folder
- uninstalling android studio

I have recently updated studio with latest version 3.0.1, it was working fine though, the problem started since last few days.

Please some one help me with this!

```
Magic number did not match
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Magic number did not match
        at com.intellij.credentialStore.kdbx.KdbxSerializerKt.readKdbxHeader(KdbxSerializer.kt:146)
        at com.intellij.credentialStore.kdbx.KdbxSerializer.createUnencryptedInputStream(KdbxSerializer.kt:61)
        at com.intellij.credentialStore.kdbx.KdbxStreamFormat.load(kdbx.kt:55)
        at com.intellij.credentialStore.kdbx.KdbxKt.loadKdbx(kdbx.kt:36)
        at com.intellij.credentialStore.KeePassCredentialStore.<init>(KeePassCredentialStore.kt:82)
        at com.intellij.credentialStore.KeePassCredentialStore.<init>(KeePassCredentialStore.kt:44)
        at com.intellij.ide.passwordSafe.impl.PasswordSafeImplKt.computeProvider(PasswordSafeImpl.kt:38)
        at com.intellij.ide.passwordSafe.impl.PasswordSafeImpl.<init>(PasswordSafeImpl.kt:46)
        at com.intellij.ide.passwordSafe.impl.PasswordSafeImpl.<init>(PasswordSafeImpl.kt)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.picocontainer.defaults.InstantiatingComponentAdapter.newInstance(InstantiatingComponentAdapter.java:193)
        at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.doGetComponentInstance(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:103)
        at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.instantiateGuarded(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:80)
        at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:63)
        at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ServiceManagerImpl$MyComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ServiceManagerImpl.java:228)
        at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getLocalInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:239)
        at com.intellij.util.pico.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponentInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:206)
        at com.intellij.openapi.components.ServiceManager.doGetService(ServiceManager.java:48)
        at com.intellij.openapi.components.ServiceManager.getService(ServiceManager.java:38)
        at com.intellij.ide.passwordSafe.PasswordSafe.getInstance(PasswordSafe.java:28)
        at org.jetbrains.android.exportSignedPackage.KeystoreStep.<init>(KeystoreStep.java:71)
        at org.jetbrains.android.exportSignedPackage.ExportSignedPackageWizard.<init>(ExportSignedPackageWizard.java:110)
        at org.jetbrains.android.actions.GenerateSignedApkAction.actionPerformed(GenerateSignedApkAction.java:74)
        at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil$1.run(ActionUtil.java:215)
        at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware(ActionUtil.java:232)
        at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.lambda$actionPerformed$0(ActionMenuItem.java:309)
        at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(FocusManagerImpl.java:929)
        at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(IdeFocusManagerImpl.java:136)
        at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.actionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:299)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
        at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.lambda$fireActionPerformed$0(ActionMenuItem.java:116)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runSyncTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:86)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.lambda$submitTransaction$1(TransactionGuardImpl.java:109)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.submitTransaction(TransactionGuardImpl.java:118)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuard.submitTransaction(TransactionGuard.java:122)
        at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.fireActionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:116)
        at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.doClick(BegMenuItemUI.java:513)
        at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.access$300(BegMenuItemUI.java:45)
        at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI$MyMouseInputHandler.mouseReleased(BegMenuItemUI.java:533)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6541)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6306)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2237)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4897)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2295)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4719)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4889)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4526)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4467)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2281)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4719)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:764)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:737)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:735)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:734)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:827)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:651)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:365)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

module gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.chigz.awesomegallery"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 4
        versionName "1.3"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    dexOptions {
        jumboMode true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.8.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    compile 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.4'
    compile 'info.hoang8f:android-segmented:1.0.6'
    compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'
    compile 'com.gjiazhe:scrollparallaximageview:1.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.2'

    // androidTestCompile'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.flaviofaria:kenburnsview:1.0.7'
    compile 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'
    compile 'com.github.hoanganhtuan95ptit:EditPhoto:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
    compile 'com.eftimoff:android-viewpager-transformers:1.0.1@aar'
    compile 'com.github.ceryle:SegmentedButton:v2.0.2'
    implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.1.3'
    compile 'com.andrognito.pinlockview:pinlockview:2.1.0'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
```

app gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: can you post your gradle file?

Comment: please have a look. i've just updated it.

Comment: These links might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33308153/gradle-dependency-causing-error-invalid-magic-number    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47808279/magic-number-mismatch-error-in-android-studio-when-generate-sign-apk

Answer (score 1):

Add `multiDexEnabled = true` in **defaultConfig**:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.chigz.awesomegallery"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 4
    versionName "1.3"
    multiDexEnabled = true // important
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

Comment: It didn't help!

Comment: Also , make sure that your Application class extends MultiDexApplication class. Alternatively , you could put this " Multidex.install(this) " in your main activity

Answer (score 1):

I have got myself into same problem few day ago. What works for me is using different JDK versions. In order to resolve this issue follow steps by [How to specify the JDK version in android studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30631386) answered by **Ben Kane**. And do clean build after done.

Comment: I've tried that same thing before posting the question but sadly it didn't work